# colour contour plot from a sequential xy file (datablocks)

Tags: gnuplot, contour

I am trying to produce a colour contour plot (the coloured projection of a surface or a "map") from a file that has the following format:

```
y1 z1 #first block 
y1 z2
y1 z3
....
y1 zn
<blank line>
y2 z1 #second block 
y2 z2
y2 z3
....
y2 zn
<blank line>
y3 z1
y3 z2
y3 z3
....
y3 zn
etc
```

Hence if you took the second column of each datablock, you turned it into a line (instead of column) and you stuck them one on top of the other, you would get your traditional matrix plot.

Is there a way to plot this thing (or to take the z columns, make them into lines, stack them and plot them)?

I have been looking into splot, set view map.

Answer (score 0):

So your xvalues are uniformly distributed? Do something like this

```
set view map
splot "data" u (column(-1)):($1):($2) w pm3d
```

If you can define your xvalues, use

```
xval(x)=1.+0.5*x #or whatever
splot "data" u (xval(column(-1))):($1):($2) w pm3d
```